# Making redundant rows names (variables) as columns and rearranging the required data in a csv file in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have the data in this format - [Source Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U5fsFVHUvFAjAE6QV68jztyhYGNVYxJ1)

and I want to rearrange my data in the following format -

```
UNIQUE-ID       TYPES      COMMON-NAME       CHEMICAL-FORMULA           DBLINKS                           MOLECULAR-WEIGHT     MONOISOTOPIC-MW
PYRIDINE-RING   Rings     pyridine-ring       (C 5)(H 5)(N 1)            NA                               79.101               NA
STEARIC_ACID    Even-St.. stearate            (C 18)(H 35)(O 2)   (BIGG "37799")..;(CHEMSPIDER "..);      283.473              284.2715304
BETA-HYDROX..  Compounds  3-&beta;-hydro..    (C 19)(H 29)(O...   (CHEBI "1724"..);(PUBCHEM "2520..);     369.495              370.1813984
OXALACETIC_A.. Compounds    ...                ....                ....                                   ....                 ...
....             ....       ...
....             ....       ...
```

So I want to arrange the data based on "UNIQUE-ID", "TYPES", "COMMON-NAME", "CHEMICAL-FORMULA", "MOLECULAR-WEIGHT" and "MONOISOTOPIC-MW". My code should consider the rows that are associated with the same id value as one single row and rearrange that information in a new dataframe - for example, every row that has id "1" in the original csv file should be rewritten in one row in the format I mentioned above.

Now the problem with the data is that for some of the "UNIQUE-ID" there are several "TYPES" (2, 3 or in some cases 5) and I want them to be separated by a semicolon(;) in a single cell in my output data like I have mentioned in the table above (see "DBLINKS" column for example)

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :-**

From the "DBLINKS" columns the main information I want to fetch is only "BIGG ID no.", "CHEMSPIDER ID no.", "CAS ID no.", "PUBCHEM ID no." and "CHEBI ID no." but I will figure that out later if it's so complex to implement.

I am not sure but I was thinking of using the reshape function in R for this but not sure about the use of parameters in my specific case.

Any help to achieve the desired result is genuinely appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Link to the sample data file - [Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z_mEDtKQDOJf-T_7Y105a4fHnrdWxfgh)

**EDIT: Further Clarification :-**

I want my final output to be like this (example is a made up dummy data not the actual data for the sake of simplicity to understand) -

```
UNIQUE-ID    TYPES       COMMON-NAME    CHEMICAL-FORMULA       DBLINKS                       MOLECULAR-WEIGHT    MONOISOTOPIC-MW

ID-1          A           C-Name-1      (C 5)(H 5)(N 1)        Detail-1                          79.101            NA   
ID-2          B; C; D     C-Name-2      (C 18)(H 35)(O 2)      Detail-2; Detail-3                283.473          284.27    
ID-3          E; F        C-Name-3      (C 19)(H 29)(O 5)(S 1) Detail-2; Detail-1; Detail-5      369.495          370.18
```

from the following data format (csv file) that I have now. The source data looks something like this -

```
Variable         Content       Id
UNIQUE-ID         ID-1          1
TYPES             A             1
COMMON-NAME       C-Name-1      1
CHEMICAL-FORMULA  (C 5)         1
CHEMICAL-FORMULA  (H 5)         1
CHEMICAL-FORMULA  (N 1)         1
DBLINKS           Detail-1      1
MOLECULAR-WEIGHT  79.101        1
UNIQUE-ID         ID-2          2
TYPES             B             2
TYPES             C             2
TYPES             D             2
COMMON-NAME       C-Name-2      2
CHEMICAL-FORMULA  (C 18)        2
CHEMICAL-FORMULA  (H 35)        2
CHEMICAL-FORMULA  (O 2)         2
DBLINKS           Detail-2      2
DBLINKS           Detail-3      2
MOLECULAR-WEIGHT  283.473       2
MONOISOTOPIC-MW   284.27        2
UNIQUE-ID         ID-3          3
TYPES             E             3
TYPES             F             3
COMMON-NAME       C-Name-3      3
CHEMICAL-FORMULA  (C 19)        3           
CHEMICAL-FORMULA  (H 29)        3
CHEMICAL-FORMULA  (O 5)         3
CHEMICAL-FORMULA  (S 1)         3
DBLINKS           Detail-2      3
DBLINKS           Detail-1      3
DBLINKS           Detail-5      3
MOLECULAR-WEIGHT  369.495       3
MONOISOTOPIC-MW   370.18        3
```

Comment: Based on what I understand of your question I would look at the gather and spread functions from tidyr. If you give a simple set of example data (no chemical names just ID: A, B, C for example) and a table showing the desired result that would make it easier to give you code that works on the toy example but doesn't require us to get into the complexities of your specific case.

Comment: @see24 - Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my question with the simple dummy data to understand clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it with `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table("test.txt", header = T) 

df2 <- df %>% group_by(Variable, Id) %>% 
  summarise(Content2 = paste(Content, collapse = ";")) %>% 
  spread(key = Variable, value = Content2) %>% 
  select("UNIQUE-ID", TYPES, "COMMON-NAME", "CHEMICAL-FORMULA", DBLINKS, 
         "MOLECULAR-WEIGHT", "MONOISOTOPIC-MW")

df2
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  `UNIQUE-ID` TYPES `COMMON-NAME` `CHEMICAL-FORMULA`    DBLINKS            `MOLECULAR-WEIGH~ `MONOISOTOPIC-M~
  <chr>       <chr> <chr>         <chr>                 <chr>              <chr>             <chr>           
1 ID-1        A     C-Name-1      (C5);(H5);(N1)        Detail-1           79.101            NA              
2 ID-2        B;C;D C-Name-2      (C18);(H35);(O2)      Detail-2;Detail-3  283.473           284.27          
3 ID-3        E;F   C-Name-3      (C19);(H29);(O5);(S1) Detail-2;Detail-1~ 369.495           370.18
```

If you want to learn more about each of the functions used here check out [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks much! And it's a great blog. Thanks for sharing!